JSON Post requests via SendWinHttpRequest with VBA
I am trying to use SendWinHTTPRequest to get data as there are large amount of records that can be retrieved and XMLHttp60/ServerXMLHttp60/WinHttpRequest do not support processing the data in chunks, so I can prevent out of memory issues.
All the headers seem to work well, I'm able to initialize the connection, I'm able send my jwt bearer token, just as I was with the previous mentioned libraries, but... I am not able to get WinHttpSendRequest to actually push the req.body over. I am able to get the error response just fine, but the body of the request isn't getting sent so I can only get errors, and not any useful data.
I've tried using WinHttpWriteData and it always indicates that bytesWritten is 0, and you'll see from below I've been trying various things with the headers to play around with what might work.  But none of it helps or it will make it where the send is entirely unsuccessful
Here's my declarations of the various WinHttp functions in case those are relevant, I know to get to this point I had to mess with the way I had defined these quite a bit
'GetLastError - rarely returns anything useful, mostly just 0
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Long
' Declare API functions from WinHTTP library
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpAddRequestHeaders Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hRequest As LongPtr, ByVal sHeader As LongPtr, ByVal lHeaderLength As Long, ByVal lModifiers As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpOpen Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal sAgent As String, ByVal lAccessType As Long, ByVal sProxyName As String, ByVal sProxyBypass As String, ByVal lFlags As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpConnect Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hSession As LongPtr, ByVal pswzServerName As LongPtr, ByVal nServerPort As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpCloseHandle Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hHandle As LongPtr) As Boolean
Public Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpSetOption Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hInternet As LongPtr, ByVal lOption As Long, ByRef lBuffer As LongPtr, ByVal lBufferLength As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpOpenRequest Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hHttpSession As LongPtr, ByVal sVerb As LongPtr, ByVal sObjectName As LongPtr, ByVal VersionTuple As LongPtr, ByVal sReferer As LongPtr, ByVal sAcceptTypes As Long, ByVal lFlags As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpSendRequest Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hRequest As LongPtr, ByVal sHeaders As LongPtr, ByVal lHeadersLength As Long, ByVal sOptional As LongPtr, ByVal lOptionalLength As Long, ByVal lTotalLength As Long, ByVal lContext As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpReceiveResponse Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hRequest As LongPtr, ByVal lReserved As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpQueryDataAvailable Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hRequest As LongPtr, ByRef lNumberOfBytesAvailable As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpReadData Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hRequest As LongPtr, ByVal sBuffer As String, ByVal lNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, ByRef lNumberOfBytesRead As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WinHttpWriteData Lib "WinHttp" (ByVal hRequest As LongPtr, ByVal lpBuffer As LongPtr, ByVal dwNumberOfBytesToWrite As Long, ByVal lpdwNumberOfBytesWritten As Long) As Boolean


Dim authHeader As String
        authHeader = "Authorization: Bearer " & token
       
        Dim headersset As Boolean
        'headersset = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hHttpRequest, StrPtr(authHeader), Len(authHeader), &H20000000)
        'If headersset = False Then Stop
        Dim contentheader As String
        contentheader = "Content-Length: " & LenB(json)
        'headersset = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hHttpRequest, StrPtr(contentheader), Len(contentheader), &H20000000)
        'If headersset = False Then Stop
        
        Dim contenttype As String
        contenttype = "Content-Type:'application/json'"
        'contenttype = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        'headersset = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hHttpRequest, StrPtr(contenttype), Len(contenttype), &H20000000)
        'If headersset = False Then Stop
        
        Dim accepttype As String
        accepttype = "Accept:'application/json'"
        'headersset = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hHttpRequest, StrPtr(accepttype), Len(accepttype), &H20000000)
        'If headersset = False Then Stop
        
        'Dim encodingheader As String
        'encodingheader = "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
        'headersset = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hHttpRequest, StrPtr(encodingheader), Len(encodingheader), &H20000000)
        'If headersset = False Then Stop
        
        
        header = authHeader & vbCrLf & contentheader & vbCrLf & contenttype & vbCrLf & accepttype & vbCrLf

 If WinHttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest, StrPtr(header), Len(header), StrPtr(json), Len(json), Len(json), 0) Then
    ... after this I sometimes use If WinHttpWriteData ...
    ... and then WinHttpQueryDataAvailable / WinHttpReadData and these both seem to be working fine, at least for errors... 

The server side of this is NodeJS using express, where I can see that the json is not coming over as it was before when I was using the other mentioned libraries, I've looked at the entire req object there but nothing stands out as to why it's not receiving the json.
json variable here is just a standard string of json converted from a dictionary object via jsonConverter.convertToJson
The headers are similarly standard strings, but I've tried making json a byte array using this function, but it doesn't seem to help
Function StrToBytes(ByVal str As String) As Byte()
    Dim utf8() As Byte
    utf8 = StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode)
    StrToBytes = utf8
End Function




StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode) doesn't convert to UTF-8. Instead, use WideCharToMultibyte

Wil give that a shot.

You may also consider using ado.stream for converting Ansi or Unicode strings to byte array.
